# Python request object return through socket

Tags: python, sockets, object, return, send

My setup is as follows:

Python 2.6 (embedded in commercial app) uses *subprocess* to launch an external script in (external) python 2.7.
The external script then uses the socket module to send python commands back to embedded python.
The socket is initialized with the following code:

```
self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

And I send commands using:

```
self.sock.send("print ('hello, world!')")
```

This is working quite well at the moment. I am able to send all the commands I want, and control the program nicely.

**My question:** how can I request to be sent information back through the socket?
I need to ask the program to give me a list of strings, for example. But I have a hard time grasping how the embedded python would send any data back through my open socket?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you want the output from a command such as `print("Hello world")` to be returned through the socket?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , I should have used a different command, like: `str(45)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always have a bidirectional socket communication.

When the external python send something, always send in a tuple where one of the arguments can specify that you are asking for something.

Let me give an example,

Setup a bidirectional socket communication (Simple client-server model- synchronous or asynchronous depends on what your project/app requires.)

2.7 sends a tuple like this -

```
(<command>, 1)
```

The 1 indicating that you want the output of the command that you sent ( which you said is working, would be sent back to 2.7.

So, when 2.6 receives the tuple, the 0th position of the tuple always represents the command it is trying to send, and the 1st position represents the send back argument.

Using a simple if-else condition, you can check if it is 1, then send back the result to 2.7 - otherwise not.

Fairly simple logic.

Comment: thank you for your response. This sounds like a good solution.  Would I need to pickle an object by hand before sending it through the socket?

Comment: yes, i believe so. To send an object via sockets in python, you need to serialize them at sending and de-serialize at receiving which can be done by pickle.